# Elasticsearch flexible search

Tags: elasticsearch

Does anyone have experience with Elasticsearch and getting the searches to be more flexible?

Currently, if I have a query "House" it will return the correct items back. but if "Hous" is typed in, nothing gets returned. Also, if I search "O.J." it will return O.J. but if I wanted to search OJ I get nothing.

Comment: Your question is is just a "help, I don't know anything about elasticsearch. Please teach me". You haven't show what you have tried to do. We have documentation (http://www.elasticsearch.org) and large archive of mails in the elasticsearch forum (http://www.elasticsearch.org/community/). Also, you might try reading other stackoverflow answers like stackoverflow.com/questions/9421358/filename-search-with-elasticsearch/9432450

Comment: Can you give an example of a query you are sending to ES?

Answer (score 0):

use **prefixing**:

```
bool: {
    must: [
        {
            multi_match: {
                query: "your text query", 
                type: "phrase_prefix",
                max_expansions: 4,
                fields: ["field1", "field2"]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

you can also add **fuzziness**, this will allow dynamic mutations but may yield to less accurate results.